# Web scraping table using python specific columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

Web scraping table using python specific columns

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/today-share-price'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
print(tables[1][1])
```

Comment: import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/today-share-price'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
print(tables[1][1])

Comment: `len(tables)` gives 1 so you can address merely `tables[0]`. Moreover, `type(tables[0])` gives `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` which can't be simply indexable, I guess…

Comment: Consider writing a more descriptive question to let know other users what you are trying to achieve. @AjukbaCoder

Answer (score 0):

### What is happening:

Pandas module "read_html(url)" returns a list of all the tables present in the webpage you want to scrape. In the current page ('https://www.sharesansar.com/today-share-price') there is only on table. So if you want to acces that table you should get the first index of the list

### Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/today-share-price'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = tables[0]
firstRow = df.iloc[[0]]
firstTwoColumns = df.iloc[: , [0, 1]]
```

For selecting specific columns/rows use pandas modules

> .iloc

> .loc